# locking cells of an array

Tags: java, multithreading

i have an array that 2 values, i want to keep the cells indipendent. So for example when one thread aquire the lock of the first position , this one doesn't block the entire structure.

```
public DataStructure(int r, int i) {
        this.r = r;
        this.i = i;
        values = new ArrayList<Integer>;
        values.add(i);
        values.add(r);
        [...]
}
public void methodA() {
         lock.lock();
          [...]
          values.get(0);
          lock.unlock();    
}
public void methodB() {
         lock.lock();
          [...]
          values.get(1);
          lock.unlock();    
}
```

*with this code when one thread acquire the lock on `methodA`  it's impossible to a different thread to get the lock on `methodB` .*

how i can do it?

Comment: Do you mean to say that your methods should be `synchronized`?

Comment: @ShishirKumar no i mean that if one thread access to first position of the array one other thread can access to other position, with no syncronization, but with parallelism

Comment: In your example code, the array is written only by the constructor, while the threads are just reading. Is the array not modified after construction?

Comment: @isnot2bad the array will be modified after construction. I can construct only one object `DataStructure`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a lock object for each cell. If you only ever have two values, then have

```
Object lock1 = new Object();
Object lock2 = new Object();
```

in your class's header and then have method A declare a synchronized block using lock1 and methodB have a synchronized block using lock2. Then each "cell" is locked independently.

e.g.

```
public void methodA() {
     synchronized(lock1) {
      [...]
      values.get(0);
      }  
}

public void methodB() {
     synchronized(lock2) {
      [...]
      values.get(1);
      }  
}
```

If you're going to have lots of independent cells, then why not declare a cell class which has a lock in it and which is used as the wrapper for the value of each cell. Then you can have a more general method for accessing the contents of a cell which would be thread safe.

e.g.

```
class Cell {
    private Object lock;
    private Object value;

    public void doSomething() {
        synchronized(lock) {
            // something happens here with the value
        }
    }
}
```

However, it's unclear what you'll gain from this attempt at threads safety.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you provide me a litte snippet, i' m a little bit confused.

Comment: I'll put it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to have a separate lock for each element in your array, you could use an array of `Lock` objects to match your other array, and lock each cell in turn.

Alternatively, you could look into using one of the concurrent Collections like the [`CopyOnWriteArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CopyOnWriteArrayList.html) for example or the [`ConcurrentHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), depending on your needs.

These collections are thread safe and take care of the locking for you.

Comment: How would a "concurrent collection" help here?  If the program needs to lock access to a particular member of a collection, then it's going to need that lock regardless of whether or not the collection object itself is thread safe.  Thread safety is not composeable:  If you build a program entirely from thread-safe components, that will not in-and-of-itself make your program thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from the question, the concurrent list implementation in `java.util.concurrent` may be of some help to you.

You should be looking for `CopyOnWriteArrayList` class in this package.

Refer to a previous SO question, which explains it perfectly.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10397154/2867032

> The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` class is an interesting case. It avoids the
>   concurrency bottleneck on read-only operations such as get and
>   contains, but it does this by doing a lot more work in mutating
>   operations, and by modifying the visibility rules. Furthermore, the
>   mutating operations lock the entire list, and are therefore a
>   concurrency bottleneck. These properties mean that
>   `CopyOnWriteArrayList` can't be called a general purpose concurrent
>   list.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: for question updates, i can't create more object instance, i must work only with one object instance.